# Inserting text/data into template rendered textarea

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I have a form with many `<textarea>` fields. They are all being rendered to my template.

Can I pre-fill this type of field with data using Django templates? I am also using [Django Widget Tweaks](https://github.com/kmike/django-widget-tweaks), which although seems relevant - lacks support for this as far as I can see.

**What I'm going for:**

```
<textarea>{{ data }}</textarea>
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

I would like the data to be persistent in the field. I tried using `placeholder="my data"`, but this of course means as soon as someone clicks, the data disappears.

Comment: <textarea>Lorem ipsum</textarea>? Do you have access to the html so you can just write that in just like it is in your example? (I know nothing about django - perhaps obviously, haha)

Comment: So what's wrong with the example you give? There's no reason why that wouldn't work. Or you could use the forms framework to do it for you.

Comment: @DanielRoseman You're right it should work. I tried this example without CSS and Javascript and it worked. It is likely that the problem is coming from a styling property.